# Индексация страницы по мета-тегу robots: Запрещена. Как ее разрешить?

Tags: wordpress

Друзья подскажите пожалуйста. Я хотел купить ссылок для одного сайта на бирже, но на все страницы и сайт в целом идет такая инфа "Индексация страницы по мета-тегу robots:Запрещена", где искать и как этот мета-тэг, чтобы убрать. Файла robots.txt на этом сайте нет! Заранее всем спасибо за ответы

Comment: Ищите в создаваемом HTML  

    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
Возможно, причина в этом.

Comment: открыл страницу в коде нашел следующие строки:
<!-- robots -->
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="none" />

Comment: http://lgroup.kz/uslugi_l-group/apostil-dokumentov-i-legalizaciya вот эта страница